# sed regex search not giving proper results

Tags: regex, search, sed

My file have text in multiple lines in following format

> number:characters

example

> 123:dfgd
>    3:hjdfg
>   23423:fdlgj

I want to extract all lines where number part has only one digit using following sed

```
sed '/^\d:/p' file.txt
```

But this is printing all the lines. Please point out the issue in the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]:/p' file
3:hjdfg
```

- `-n` is to suppress regular output
- `[0-9]` is to match a digit (`\d` isn't supported by `sed` regex even in extended regex mode)